# Questions about managing subcription payment status in my database

Tags: php, mysql, payment, subscription, payment-processing

Developing an app that people pay a monthly subscription to use. They can pay monthly or a year in advance for a reduced price.

What is the best way to make sure they are up to date?

My best guess is, when they make a payment, an expiration date is calculated and then each time they log in the app checks to see if the current date is < the expiration date.

What's the best way to do this? What are the pitfalls? What are necessary maintenance requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an expiration date for their subscription is definitely the way to go. I can't think of any pitfalls to this, and it's probably by far the simplest solution. Also, there aren't any real maintenance requirements - the app can simply check if the current date is before the expiration date, and if it is it runs, otherwise it outputs a message.